# How to join two tables using Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have two entities similar to the following:

```
Doctor:
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Long id;
...

DoctorSpeciality:
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "DOCTOR_ID")
private Doctor doctor;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SPECIALITY_ID")
private Speciality speciality;
```

I want to join these, to retrieve all Doctors, given the SpecialityId, by DoctorRepository, using JPA Specifications.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: FWIW There is no such thing as "JPA Specifications" or "JPA Repository" or "JPA Query". That is Spring Data JPA (!= JPA API). Tags fixed

Answer (score 3):

In your `DoctorRepository` try this

```
@Query("Select d from Doctor d where d.speciality.id = :id")
List<Doctor> findAllBySpeciality(@Param("id") long id);
```

**Update 1 :** With the mappings you provided the following JPQL is working.

```
@Query("Select ds.doctor from DoctorSpeciality ds where ds.speciality.id = :id")
List<Doctor> findAllBySpeciality(@Param("id") long id);
```

Comment: I have this query successfully running:

select * from doctor join doctor_speciality on doctor.id= doctor_speciality.doctor_id where doctor_speciality.speciality_id=2

But I want to achieve the same thing using JPA specification.

Comment: @Ganesan check the updated answer. This JPQL is working on my machine successfully.

Comment: The query I said above worked fine.

But I want to do it by Specification like this:

`public static Specification<Doctor> findBySpeciality(Speciality speciality) {

  return (root, query, cb) -> {
   Join<Doctor, DoctorSpeciality> specialityDoctor = root.join("doctor");
   Join<DoctorSpeciality, Speciality> specialityRelation = specialityDoctor.join("speciality");
   return cb.equal(specialityRelation.get("speciality"), speciality);
  };

 }`

It's not working and I need help with this.